# How do i use Ressources embedded into the application without visual studio

Tags: c#, resources, icons, dotnet-cli

I have a GUI project using winforms, and want to use some icons inside it.
I don't use Visual Studio for this, but build it with dotnet cli.
While it is working when they are loaded from seperate files, i want them inside the executable as a resource. I added the whole folder via this entry in the csproj:

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\*.png" />
```

But how would i reference them and e.g. load them into an Image object?
All examples i have found are using the GUI of Visual studio for it.